# Show equality of sets : Is there a better way?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let \begin{equation*}S:=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+\left \{a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\right \} \ \text{ and } \ T:=\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\left \{b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\mid b\in \mathbb{R}\right \}\end{equation*}

I want to show that $S=T$. I have done the following:

Let $x\in S$. Then \begin{equation*}x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} with $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

We have that: 
\begin{align*}x&=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\\ & =\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ -2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+(2+a)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \\ & =\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+(2+a)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\in T\end{align*}

So $S\subseteq T$.

Let $x\in h$. Then \begin{equation*}x=\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} with $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

We have that:
\begin{align*}x&=\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\\ & =\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ -2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+(-2+b)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \\ & =\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+(-2+b)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\in S\end{align*}

So $T\subseteq S$.

From the two relations we get $S=T$.

$$$$

Is there maybe a better way to show that?

Comment: Let $S=\{p+t\cdot v\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$ and $T=\{q+t\cdot v\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$. We have $p=q-2\cdot v$ so $T=S$.

Comment: Having that $p=q-2v$ how does it follow that T=S$ ? @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: Because (for some suitable $t$) $$x\in S\iff x=p+t\cdot v\iff x=q+(t+2)\cdot v\iff x\in T$$

Comment: I see!! Thanks a lot!! :-) @MaximilianJanisch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to note that the direction vectors are the same (we need in general they are parallel) and solve for

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+x\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \iff x\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-4 \\ 2 \\ -2\end{pmatrix} \iff x=-2$$

indeed from this it follows that by $a=(b-2)$ they represents exactly the same set.

Comment: Does this suffices because the sets describe lines?

Comment: @MaryStar It suffices since by $a=(b-2)$ they are exactly the same set.

Comment: The set describes lines, or not? Since the lines have the same direction vector, they describe the same lines? Or have I understood that wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes of course! It is a line (or an affine subspace of dimension one). Anyway the same procedure can be also applied for n-dimensiona subspaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)